# Persp in r, how to fix surface extends beyond the box

Tags: r, plot, regression, predict, perspective

I am trying to create a clean perspective plot. I am able to create a nice plot with a predictive "mesh" based on my data, however it extends past my x and y limits. My code is below. I apologize for the lack of reproducible data.

```
dat<-data.frame(x,y,z);rm(x,y,z)
m1i<-(lm(z~poly(y,2)*x, data=dat))
xr<-range(dat$x)
xseq<-seq((xr[1]-1),xr[2], length=30)#the subtraction just made my prediction limits larger than what my data has- so it predicts for data I don't have
yr<-range(dat$y)
yseq<-seq((yr[1]-0.5),yr[2], length=30)#same as above, just so my predictions started at 0
zp<-outer(xseq,yseq, function(a,b) predict(m1i, newdata=data.frame(x=a,y=b)))
nrz<-nrow(zp)
ncz<-ncol(zp)
jet.colors<-colorRampPalette(c("grey60","white"))
nbcol<-100
color<-jet.colors(nbcol)
zfacet<-zp[-1,-1]+zp[-1,-ncz]+zp[-nrz,-1]+zp[-nrz,-ncz]
facetcol<-cut(zfacet,nbcol)

res<-persp(x=xseq,y=yseq,z=zp, col=color[facetcol],theta=40, phi=10, 
ylab="Set Time (hr)", xlab="Distance (m)",
       zlab="Proportion Captured", nticks=5, ticktype="detailed", 
xlim=c(0,5),
       ylim=c(0,4), zlim=c(0,1.1))
```

I get a warning when I run the code

> In persp.default(x = xseq, y = yseq, z = zp, col = color[facetcol],  :
>     surface extends beyond the box

I would like to cut off the surface so it ends at my box limits.

[perspPlotExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnAgw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why you can get this warning. Either your `x`, `y` or `z` variable extends beyond the limits you set. The fix for the `x` and `y` variables is to cut the variables where necessary. The `z` variable you can set to `NA`. Below is a reproducible example.

```
# generate data
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N, 2, 0.5)
y <- rnorm(N, 2, 0.4)
z <- 0.1*y^2 * x + rnorm(N)
dat<-data.frame(x,y,z);rm(x,y,z)

# run code from question (not copied)

# set z beyond limit to NA
zp[zp < 0] <- NA
zp[zp > 1.1] <- NA

# plot
persp(x = xseq[xseq > 0 & xseq < 5],
      y = yseq[yseq > 0 & yseq < 4],
      z = zp[xseq > 0 & xseq < 5, yseq > 0 & yseq < 4], 
      theta = 40, phi = 10, 
      ylab = "Set Time (hr)", xlab = "Distance (m)",
      zlab = "Proportion Captured", nticks = 5, ticktype = "detailed", 
      xlim = c(0,5),
      ylim = c(0,4), 
      zlim = c(0,1.1))
```